# How to get multiple checkbox toggle switches values when on change event via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have implemented toggle switch based on checkbox in my website. When I use one toggle switch I can able to get the value of the checkbox which I click. But I when I implement two or more toggle switches I cannot get the value of checkbox which click. It always returning the value of first the checkbox.

You can understand what I'm saying by clicking second toggle switch that I created on the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/wughm90b/2/

This is my html code:

```
<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" checked data-value="one" >
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>

<br>

<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" data-value="two">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".switch", function () {
    alert($(this).find('input').data('value'));
});
```

Comment: ID cannot be same for both div

Comment: @akshay No. it's not the issue. The issue was I'm using the same id for the both input tags. That's the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicated the id for the two swtiches. Please find the corrected code below

```
<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" checked data-value="one" >
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>

<br>

<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" data-value="two">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-2"></label>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on("change", ".switch", function () {
 alert($(this).find('input').data('value'));
});
```

```css
/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
#wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.settings {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.settings .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.settings .question,
.settings .switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.settings .question {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */
.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 1 - ROUND
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 58px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 2 - ROUND FLAT
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #8ce196;
}

/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 3 - YES NO
============================================================ */
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  content: attr(data-off);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  content: attr(data-on);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" checked data-value="one" >
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>

<br>

<div class="switch" id="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" data-value="two">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-2"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks..  I wasn't cool by the time of doing this coding.. That's why I couldn't able to find out this small issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

id names given must be unique.

Please check the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d4camgf/).

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.